# Targeting the closest class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning javascript and ran into a problem.
I'm trying to target the closest class and change the value, but I just keep getting Cannot read property 'innerText' of null at HTMLUListElement.
Is this not possible or is there another way I should look into?
Any help or guidance is appreciated.

```
<div id="someId">
<h2>Test</h2>
<ul>
    <li>
        <p class="amount">5</p>
        <span class="name">My Name</span>
        <button class="plus">Plus</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="amount">10</p>
        <span class="name">My Name 2</span>
        <button class="plus">Plus</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="amount">15</p>
        <span class="name">My Name 3</span>
        <button class="plus">Plus</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
const someList = document.querySelector('#someId ul');

someList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if (e.target.className === 'plus') {
    let newValue = e.target.closest('.amount');
    newValue.innerText += "5";
}
});
```

I've changed the .amount to lots of different things, p and li > p etc but no luck.

Comment: `.closest()` goes up the dom/xpath looking at ancestors. your `p.amount` is a sibling, not an ancestor, so nothing is returned from your `.closest()` call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.closest()` goes up the dom/xpath looking at ancestors. your `p.amount` is a sibling, not an ancestor, so nothing is returned from your `.closest()`

There is no single core js method for what you want to do.  jQuery offers a function called [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) which is the closest to what you are intending to do, if you want to use it. But for pure javascript, the gist is to go up the dom/xpath tree and then back down.

There are different ways you can do it, depending on what selectors you want to be "anchors".  @doodlemeister 's answer is one way to do it, but IMO it is not great because it may not be as flexible as you might like. It assumes going up to the first parent and then back down to the first child. IOW it expects your html structure to be exactly as you have it now.

A more flexible way is something like this:

```
const someList = document.querySelector('#someId ul');
someList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'plus') {
        let newValue = e.target.closest('li').querySelector('.amount');
        newValue.innerText = +newValue.innerText + 5;
    }
});
```

You can then adjust the `.closest()` selector if needed, and you use `querySelector()` to go back down the dom/xpath from there and target by your originally intended class.

Comment: Using both `.closest()` and `.querySelector()` is probably the best solution for this situation.

Comment: This is really cool, works like a charm! I changed the correct answer to this one, too low rep to upvote tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`.closest` looks at ancestors, and `.amount` is not one. You can instead go to the `.parentNode` and then the `.firstElementChild`.

And I'd personally use `.matches()` instead of comparing the class name for exact equality.

```
someList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('.plus')) {
        let newValue = e.target.parentNode.firstElementChild;
        newValue.innerText += "5";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! But If the P tag wasnt first child, I would have to use children[foo]? There is no simple way of targeting by the class name?

Comment: @Crayon's answer uses `.querySelector` from the `.closest("li")` to target it by class. You should choose that answer instead.

Comment: @Shamaran i just posted an answer addressing the very thing you asked about!

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can target the parent and select the matching child

```js
const someList = document.querySelector('#someId ul');
someList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'plus') {
    let newValue = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('.amount').innerText += "5";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="someId">
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="amount">5</p>
      <span class="name">My Name</span>
      <button class="plus">Plus</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="amount">10</p>
      <span class="name">My Name 2</span>
      <button class="plus">Plus</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="amount">15</p>
      <span class="name">My Name 3</span>
      <button class="plus">Plus</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.closest()` is now a DOM method. But your solution is  good.